Approximating the function 1 in Sobolev energy
I would like to find a sequence of smooth compactly supported functions $ u_n \in C^\infty_c([0,+\infty))$ with the following two properties:

$u_n \to 1$ a.e. on $[0,+\infty)$ as $n \to + \infty$;
$\int_0^\infty |u_n'(t)|^2 t dt \to 0$ as $n \to + \infty$.

I wasn't able to construct them explicitly so I am starting to think this may be false. Any help would be appreciated!

There is such a sequence. The key property is that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}$ diverges, so that we can not bound $\int u_n'dt$ via $\int |u_n'|^2tdt$, thus we can lose the desired height of $1$ while not violating the second condition.
Specifically, let $u_n = 1$ on $[0, n]$. We want to extend it to a function on $[n, n^2]$ (say, I chose this interval because $\int_n^{n^2} \frac{1}{t} = \log(n)\to \infty$) such that $u_n(n) = 1, u_n(n^2) = 0$ and $\int_n^{n^2} |u_n'(t)|^2tdt$ is small. Cauchy--Schwarz inequality tells us that
$$1 = \left|\int_{n}^{n^2}u_n'(t)dt\right|^2 \le \int_n^{n^2} |u_n'(t)|^2tdt \int_n^{n^2}\frac{1}{t}dt,$$
and, what's more important, we can turn the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality into an equality by choosing an appropriate function $u_n'(t)$. So, let $u_n'(t) = -\frac{1}{t\log(n)}$ for $n < t < n^2$. Then
$$\int_n^{n^2} |u_n'(t)|^2tdt = \int_n^{n^2} \frac{1}{t \log^2(n)}dt = \frac{1}{\log(n)}\to 0$$
while
$$\int_n^{n^2} u_n'(t)dt = -\int_n^{n^2} \frac{1}{t\log(n)}dt = -1.$$
So, the function is compactly supported and is from the appropriate Sobolev class with the required conditions $1$ and $2$. To make it $C^\infty$ (while preserving these conditions) change $u_n'$ from above to a smooth function compactly supported on $[n, n^2]$ with the total integral $-1$ approximating our choice from above.

Thank you for your answer! Do you think the sam technique can be used to handle the case in which instead of the weight $t$ we have some $t^\alpha$ with $\alpha>1$?

@Bremen000 for $t^\alpha, \alpha > 1$ there is no such sequence, because $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^\alpha}dt < \infty$, but all the ideas are there.

I see the heuristic. Hopefully I can show that this sequence doesn't exist even if I don't see how I could get a contradiction

@Bremen000 Hint: pick any $x_0 > 0$ for which $u_n(x_0)\to 1$. Then $\int_{x_0}^\infty u_n'(x) dx\to -1$. On the other hand, show that this integral must tend to $0$ under your second assumption.

Let $u\in\mathscr{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ equals $1$ in a vicinity of the origin. Consider $u_n(t) = u(\ln(t)/n)$ which is compactly supported in $[0,+\infty)$.
Point 1. is immediately satisfied. As for 2.
$$\int_0^{\infty} |u_n'(t)|^2t\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 t} u'(\ln(t)/n)^2\,\mathrm{d} t = \frac{1}{n} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u'(s)^2 \,\mathrm{d}s,$$
which indeed goes to $0$.

Thank you! Maybe adding a $t+1$ is necessary, but the proof seems to work! Do you think this could be adapted to the case in which the weight is $t^\alpha$ with $\alpha>1$ instead of $t$?

I didn't check it but you can surely try :) I did not get your point with $t+1$.
